# Angularfire not able to retrieve key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

I have this code block here;

```
 return this.db.list(`users/${currentId}/chatThreads/`)
      .map((thread) => {
        thread.map((t) => {
          let x = {
            key: t, // <- Undefined? Where's the key
            count: t.$value,
          }
          console.log(x);
          return x;
        })
      });
```

And chatThreads looks something like this
[image]

Trying to transform this object to simple key value JSON (using `x`) above. However, I can get the count to work with value `1` but the key is undefined.

What am I missing here?

Comment: isn't it `this.db.list(`users/${currentId}/chatThreads/`).valueChanges().map()`?

Comment: this is angularfire.. I don't think valueChanges() exists.. (Btw this is not realtime database)

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.db.list(`users/${currentId}/chatThreads/`)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map((thread) => {
        thread.map((t) =>
          return t.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() 
     })
        })
      });
```

Comment: What is `snapshotChanges()` ?

Comment: If you use the angular 5 version, this link is explained in more detail: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md